# How to create new git repository with SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Here is what I did so far (in SourceTree):

1. Choose "Create New Repository"
2. choose a destination path ("hallo")
3. create a file in the "hallo" directory
4. commit that file (which creates a local master branch)
5. create a new remote (ssh://xxx@192.168.162.20:22/srv/git/hallo)
6. push to remote branch

Now I get an error:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
>
> Pushing to ssh://xxx@192.168.162.20:22/srv/git/hallo
>
> fatal: '/srv/git/hallo' does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I am working with a a dozen of other repositiories without any difficulties on that server. So it can't be an access or ssh problem. I also double checked the ip address of the server.

If I start the terminal and write "git remote -v" I get:

> origin  ssh://xxx@192.168.162.20:22/srv/git/hallo (fetch)
> origin  ssh://xxx@192.168.162.20:22/srv/git/hallo (push)

If I try to push ("git push origin master") I get:

> fatal: '/srv/git/hallo' does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have no clue what I'm missing.
Can you help?

Comment: Did you create a new repo on the ssh server?

Comment: Try to change git folder to another folder, your error may be caused by write permission.

Comment: @VonC: No, I didn't. Do I have to? I thought pushing a commit will do this for me. Is this wrong?

Comment: @ Do Nhu Vy: I have many other repos in the same directory(srv/git/) which are behaving normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, I didn't. Do I have to? I thought pushing a commit will do this for me.

Yes you should create a remote repo first.

Connect to ssh://xxx@192.168.162.20:22, and create a bare repo:

```
cd /srv/git/
git init --bare hallo
```